# Python pickle/unpickle a list to/from a file

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a = [['a string', [0, 0, 0], [22, 'bee sting']], ['see string', 
    [0, 2, 0], [22, 'd string']]]
```

and am having problems saving it and retrieving it.

I can save it ok using pickle:

```
with open('afile','w') as f:
    pickle.dump(a,f)
```

but get the following error when I try to load it:

```
pickle.load('afile')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#116>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.load('afile')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 841, in __init__
    self.readline = file.readline
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

I had thought that I could convert to a numpy array and use `save`, `savez` or `savetxt`. However I get the following error:

```
>>> np.array([a])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#122>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([a])
ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence
```

Comment: Instead of pickle.load('afile') do pickle.load(open('afile'))

Comment: Of course! thanks - Why don't you put that as an answer..

Comment: You can't easily convert what you have to a `numpy.array` as it has an irregular shape.  You'd have to make a big regular array and then fill in all the data with `NaN` or something like that… essentially what `pandas` does for you.  It's probably overkill for your small list, however.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Decided to make it as an answer. pickle.load method expects to get a file like object, but you are providing a string instead, and therefore an exception. So instead of:

```
pickle.load('afile')
```

you should do:

```
pickle.load(open('afile', 'rb'))
```

Comment: maybe `open('afile', 'rb')`.  Note from the `pickle` documentation: *Be sure to always open pickle files created with protocols >= 1 in binary mode.*

Answer (score 18):

To add to @ Rapolas K's answer:

I found that I had problems with the file not closing so used this method:

```
with open('afile','rb') as f:
     pickle.load(f)
```