# Python - Store variables in a list that save each time program restarts

Tags: python, list, bots, irc, twitch

I am stuck on a seemingly simple task with a Python Twitch IRC Bot I'm developing for my channel. I have a points system all figured out, and I thought it was working, but I found out that every time I restart the program, the list that contains balances of users resets.

This is because I declare the empty list at the beginning of the script each time the program is run. If a user chats and they aren't in the list of welcomed users, then the bot will welcome them and add their name to a list, and their balance to a corresponding list.

Is there someway I can work around this resetting problem and make it so that it won't reset the list every time the program restarts? Thanks in advance, and here's my code:

```
welcomed = []
balances = []

def givePoints():
    global balances
    threading.Timer(60.0, givePoints).start()
    i = 0
    for users in balances:
        balances[i] += 1
        i += 1
def welcomeUser(user):
    global welcomed
    global balances
    sendMessage(s, "Welcome, " + user + "!")
    welcomed.extend([user])
    balances.extend([0])

givePoints()
#other code here...

if '' in message:
    if user not in welcomed:
        welcomeUser(user)
break
```

(I had attempted to use global variables to overcome this problem, however they didn't work, although I'm guessing I didn't use them right :P)

Comment: You can't make a list persist between executions of the script, but you can write the list to a file and read it when you start up.

Comment: I had thought about that, however would it insert the string versions of the text file into the list in a way that wouldn't allow it to iterate through the balances and increase them?

Comment: There are multiple ways to save lists such as `json` and `pickle`. You'd read that list back at restart and have the current values.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229082/python-pickle-unpickle-a-list-to-from-a-file) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module to dump and load your list. You can catch file open problems when loading the list, and use that to initialize an empty list.

```
import json

def loadlist(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'r') as listfile:
            saved_list = json.load(listfile)
    except Exception:
            saved_list = []
    return saved_list

def savelist(path, _list):
    try:
        with open(path, 'w') as listfile:
            json.dump(_list, listfile)
    except Exception:
        print("Oh, no! List wasn't saved! It'll be empty tomorrow...")
```