# how to add user input into a list that can be reused?

Tags: list, user-input

im new to programing and i am making my first program ( for the family ) and what i would like to do is ask a series of questions (no right or wrong answers) but record the answer so that the next time we use the program the previouse answer is there? (little bit more about the program: its basicly we have trouble figuring out what to eat and i wanted to make a program that randomly chooses a food according to the possative/negative answers given to the question and i know my wife will attempt to "break" the program by giveing acceptable but weird possative/negative answers example: yup yeah nah nope how ever i dont know the whole list of words she knows she always suprises me with newer words that are totaly correct ( and it doesnt help we are bilingual) so i want to out smart her by adding her responces to the program so that the next time she uses it the words will already be there without me having to manualy add it

is it even possible to do so? (i am no where near finished coding the program and it is my first project)

example:

```
import random


Order_list = ["McDonalds", "Langos(Rendeles)", "Pizza(Pasa)", "Kinai", "KFC", "Kebab", "Pizza(Forte)", "Mexicoi(Rendeles)", "Sushi", "Asiai Etelek", "Hamburger(Rendeles(nem meki/kfc))" "Pizza(Nem Pasa es nem Forte)", "Burger King"]
Stove_list = ["Carbonara", "Brassoi", "Bolognai", "Flekken", "Magvas Rantot Hus", "Curry Csirke", "Teriyaki Teszta", "Vifon Teszta", "Tojasos Nokedli"]
Oven_list = ["Rakott Teszta", "Rakott Krumpli", "Rakott Karfiol", "Rakott Kaposzta", "Mutans Hus", "Baconbe Csavart Csirke"]
Cold_lst = ["szendvics", "salata", "meleg szendvics(micro)", "Vifon Teszta"]

Available_posative_answers = []

Hungry_Q = ""
Hungry = True


while True:
    Hungry_Q = input("Éhes vagy?: ").lower()
    if Hungry_Q in ("igen", "yes"):
        Hungry = True
        if Hungry is True:
            Order = input("Van pénzed rendelni?: ").lower()
            if Order in ("yes", "igen", "van"):
                Energy = input("Van energiád főzni?: ").lower()
                if Energy in ("igen", "van", "igen van", "yes", "i do", "yes i do"):
                    Mood = input("Van kedved főzni?: ").lower()
                    if Mood in ("igen", "van", "igen van", "yes", "i do", "yes i do"):
                        Oven = input("Működik a sütő?: ").lower()
                        if Oven in ("igen", "yes"):
                            print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Order_list + Oven_list + Stove_list))
                            break
                        elif Oven in ("no", "nem"):
                            print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Order_list + Stove_list))
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
                    elif Mood in ("no", "nem", "nincs"):
                        Meleg = input("Akarsz meleg ételt enni?: ").lower()
                        if Meleg in ("igen", " yes"):
                            print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Order_list))
                            break
                        elif Meleg in ("no", "nem"):
                            print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Cold_lst))
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
                    else:
                        print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
                elif Energy in ("no", "nem", "nincs"):
                    Meleg = input("Akarsz meleg ételt enni?: ").lower()
                    if Meleg in ("igen", " yes"):
                        print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Order_list))
                        break
                    elif Meleg in ("no", "nem"):
                        print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Cold_lst))
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
                else:
                    print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
            elif Order in ("no", "nem"):
                Energy = input("Van energiád főzni?: ").lower()
                if Energy in ("igen", "van", "igen van", "yes", "i do", "yes i do"):
                    Mood = input("Van kedved főzni?: ").lower()
                    if Mood in ("igen", "van", "igen van", "yes", "i do", "yes i do"):
                        Oven = input("Működik a sütő?: ").lower()
                        if Oven in ("igen", "yes"):
                            print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Oven_list + Stove_list))
                            break
                        elif Oven in ("no", "nem"):
                            print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Stove_list))
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
                    elif Mood in ("no", "nem", "nincs"):
                        print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Cold_lst))
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
                elif Energy in ("no", "nem", "nincs"):
                    print("A választott étel: " + random.choice(Cold_lst))
                    break
                else:
                    print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
            else:
                print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
        elif Hungry is False:
            print("Akkor talán nem kéne enned!!!")
            break
        else:
            break
    elif Hungry_Q in ("nem", "no"):
        print("Akkor talán nem kéne enned!!!")
        break
    else:
        print("Érvénytelen válasz!")
```

i realy hope its possible and that the way i discribed my problem is understandable

thank you for your time and patients for reading all this but most of all thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Store variables in a list that save each time program restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643440/python-store-variables-in-a-list-that-save-each-time-program-restarts)

Comment: something like that but i have only been learning to code for about a week and i have no idea how .json files work or how i could impement them into my code