# Python saving list changes

Tags: python, list, save

```
list = []
while True:
    list.append(input())
    print(list)
```

this allows me to add whatever I want to this list. However, Is there a way that I can keep the changes to the list so that when I run the program later all of the things I previously wrote will be on the list?

EDIT: If it matters, I use PyCharm for coding and running my progams

Comment: Consider saving the list to a text file or wherever. Then you can just load the list from the source and append new records.

Comment: You'd need to dump the list to some persistent storage (e.g., a file, a database table) and read it when the program starts.

Comment: This may help: [Python pickle/unpickle a list to/from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229082/python-pickle-unpickle-a-list-to-from-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json` here.

```
import json
try:
    list = json.load(open("database.json"))
except:
    list = []
while True:
    try:
        list.append(input())
        print(list)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        json.dump(list, open('database.json', 'w'))
```

This stores the content in a file called database.json, you can end the program with `CTRL+C`

Comment: Gupta I tried that, but when I ran the program a second time the list contents had been removed

Comment: You were closing the program using?

Comment: PyCharm, and I want to be able to close it in PyCharm too

Comment: Also I tried it in python and closed it with CTRL + C and that didn't work either

Comment: After `json.dump(...` in the except clause do `exit()`

Comment: Also, not good to shadow `list`.  maybe change to `my_list` since `list` is a type

Answer (score 0):

You would need a persistence layer i.e a file system, database, `pickle`, `shelve` etc. where you can store the data present in `list` once the program has terminated. When you re-run your program, make sure it loads from the same persistence store, without initializing it to `[]` and that is how you would be able to store the elements appended to the list.

Python provides many alternatives as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the list somewhere first and then load it at the start of the program. Since it's just a simple list we can just use python pickle to save it to disk like this:

```
import pickle

try:
    with open('list.p', 'rb') as f:
        list = pickle.load(f)
except:
    list = []
while True:
    try:
        list.append(input())
        print(list)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        with open('list.p', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(list, f)
```